# What Eureka Client did before register server?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When I study the Hello world case of spring cloud Eureka [service-registration-and-discovery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/), the client can register the server without define **defaultZone** in client configuration file.

I guess client will search all the servers and ports it can access? is it correct? if not, how client can find the server and register?

Comment: it defaults to `http://localhost:8761`

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look into the [Eureka Repo](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-server/src/main/resources/eureka-client.properties) they define a default value for the `eureka.serviceUrl.default`:

```
# Since shouldUseDns is false, we use the following properties to explicitly specify the route to the eureka servers
 eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8080/eureka/v2/
```